# Derivative of $ \frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So the wolfram alpha [says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2F2%20) the answer is:

$ \frac {x}{2 \sqrt{x^2+1}}$

But when I try to take the derivative of:
$ \frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2}$

by [quotient rule](http://www.mathwords.com/d/d_assets/d42.gif), I get:
$ \frac {\frac{1}{2} \cdot (x^2+1)^{\frac {-1}{2}} \cdot 2x}{4}$

and as you can see, end up with 4 in the denominator, not 2.
So... can someone tell me what's wrong by taking the derivative using a quotient rule?

Comment: Where does your $4$ come from?

Comment: Power rule: (u'v - uv')/v^2

Comment: @dramadeur That's the quotient rule.

Comment: @Newb  yeah, sorry, I meant quotient rule.

Comment: @dramadeur: I suggest you seriously take a look at a proof of the so-called power rule, for then you will find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f, g$ be functions differentiable on an open interval $\subset \mathbb{R}.$ Let $x$ lie in the open interval and let $h > 0$ such that $x+h$ still lies in the open interval. Since
$$\frac{\frac{f(x+h)}{g(x+h)} - \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{h} = h^{-1} \frac{f(x+h)g(x) - f(x)g(x+h)}{g(x+h)g(x)} = h^{-1} \frac{g(x)\big[ f(x+h) - f(x) \big] + f(x)\big[ g(x) - g(x+h) \big]}{g(x+h)g(x)} \to \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)} - \frac{f(x)g'(x)}{g^{2}(x)} = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g^{2}(x)},$$
we see where the "square" in the denominator comes from.

In your case, since $g := 2$ on some suitable interval, it does not affected by $h$ so that you do not have to square it.

Answer (score 2):

You may just write
$$
\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\color{red}{2}} \right)'=\frac{1}{{\color{red}{2}}}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1} \right)'=\frac{1}{{\color{red}{2}}}\times\frac12 \times 2x \times \left(x^2+1\right)^{1/2-1}=\frac{1}{{\color{red}{2}}}\frac{x} {\sqrt{x^2+1}}.
$$

Comment: if you don't put 1/2 in front of the squared term, then the math doesn't work out, why?

Comment: @dramadeur If you don't have 1/2 as a factor, you get the result $\frac{x} {\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. Thanks!

Comment: can you just do it by the quotient rule? because then you get 4 in the denominator, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @dramadeur OK, I will show you how it works by the quotient rule, but you will find the same result.

Comment: yeah, show me what I did wrong, that'd be superb.

Comment: @dramadeur Your mistake is that when using (u/v)'=(u'v-uv')/v^2 with v=2, you have forgotten to multiply by v(=2) on the latter numerator...

Comment: AAAA! I see, thanks!

Comment: @dramadeur You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so we have:
$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2} = \frac 1 2 \cdot \sqrt{x^2+1} = \frac 1 2 \cdot (x^2+1)^{1/2}$$

This is a chain rule situation. We have $h(g(x))$ where $g(x) = x^2+1$ and $h(y) = y^{1/2}$. Recall that the chain rule states: $(h(g(x)))' = h'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$.

We then have that $g(x)' = 2x$ and $h(y)' = \frac 1 2 \cdot y^{-1/2} = \frac 1 {2 \sqrt{y}}$.

Then we put together $h'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$:

$$f'(x) = \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 {2 \sqrt{x^2+1}} \cdot 2x = \frac x {2\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

---

**Proof via Quotient Rule, Requested by OP**:

Reminder: the quotient rule is:

$$\left(\frac f g\right)' = \frac {f'g-g'f}{g^2}$$

And in your situation: $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}$, $g(x) = 2$

Finding $f'(x)$ is again a chain rule situation as above, whereby $f'(x) = \frac {2x} {2\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. And $g'(x) = 0$.

Now we plug this into the quotient rule formula:

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2}\right)' = \frac{\left(\frac {2x} {2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\cdot 2\right) - \left(0 \cdot \sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{4}$$

Note that the $0$ just cancels out the right side:

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2}\right)' = \frac{\frac {2x} {2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\cdot 2}{4} = \frac{\frac {2x} {2\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{2}$$

And finally:

$$\frac{\frac {2x} {2\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{2} = \frac {2x} {2\sqrt{x^2+1}} \cdot \frac 1 2 = \frac {x} {2\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: do it using the quotient rule, because for some reason it doesn't work out correctly that way. I don't need to have to rewrite my equation in order to solve it correctly. It should be solvable via a quotient rule.

Comment: @dramadeur done

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} (1 + x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$

Then we have $f'(x) = \frac{df(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times (2x) \times (x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{x}{2 \sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

And we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x^2+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2 + 1\right)^{1/2}$.

Then, $\displaystyle \begin{aligned}[t]f'(x) & = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2 + 1\right)^{-1/2} \cdot (2x)\right] \\ & = \frac{1}{2}\left[x \left(x^2 + 1\right)^{-1/2}\right] \\ & = \frac{x}{2\left(x^2 + 1\right)^{1/2}} \\ & = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}.\end{aligned}$

EDIT: If you would like to complete this with the quotient rule, then take note that the quotient rule for some function $\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$ is $\displaystyle g'(x) = \frac{v(x)u'(x) - u(x)v'(x)}{\left[v(x)\right]^2}$. Thus, for $f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2}$,

$\begin{aligned}[t] f'(x) & = \frac{2 \times \left[\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)^{-1/2}(2x)\right] - \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{2} \times (0)}{2^2} \\ & = \frac{2 \times \left[x(x^2 + 1)^{-1/2}\right]}{2^2} \\ & = \frac{x(x^2+1)^{-1/2}}{2^1} \hspace{1cm} \text{(Cancel 2 from numerator and denominator)}\\ & = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\end{aligned}.$

Comment: I see that if you isolate 1/2 then it works out, but can you try taking the derivative using the quotient rule?

Comment: See the updated post now and you should see.

Comment: yeah, I dun goofed, I forgot to multiply by the denominator in the numerator... for it's (u'v - uv')/v^2